# How to migrate akka http (using custom directives) to http4s

Tags: scala, akka-http, http4s

Let's say I define this route using Akka Http:

- POST method
- If there's a specific `header` in the `request` I will remove it but I will add a new `header` with the same value (it is like I'm replacing a `header` in the `request`). I'm using a custom `directive` here.
- Extract the body as a `case class` (SomeData)
- Finally inside the `complete` block I have some code that uses the `request` (with the `headers` processed in step 2)

It would be something like this:

```scala
  val someRoute = replaceHeaders {
      post {
        extractRequest { req =>
          entity(as[SomeData]) { someData =>
            complete {
              // some code here that uses `req` (defined 3 lines above)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

For replacing `headers` I can define a custom `directive`, similar to this:

```scala
  def replaceHeaders: Directive0 =
    mapRequest(req =>
      req.headers.find(_.is(headerToReplace)) match {
          case Some(header) =>
            req
              .removeHeader(...)
              .addHeader(...(header.value()))
          case None => req
      }
    )
```

In the first code inside the `complete` block I have access to the `request`, in particular I have access to the `headers` that has been processed by `replaceHeaders directive`.

How can I do the same using `http4s` library? Because there are no customized `directive` as in `Akka Http`.
I know I can create a function to do something similar:

```scala
  def replaceHeaders(request: Request[IO]): Headers = {
    val searchHeader = "SomeHeader"
    val newHeader = "NewHeader"

    request.headers.get(CaseInsensitiveString(searchHeader)) match {
      case Some(headerFound) =>
        request.headers
          .filterNot(_.name == CaseInsensitiveString(searchHeader))
          .put(Header(newHeader, headerFound.value))
      case None =>
        request.headers
    }
  }

  val routes: HttpRoutes[IO] = {
    val dsl = Http4sDsl[IO]
    import dsl._

    HttpRoutes.of[IO] {
      case req @ POST -> Root =>
        // replace one header for another
        val newHeaders = replaceHeaders(req)

        IO {
          Response[IO](Status.Ok)
            .withHeaders(newHeaders)
            .withEntity[String]("Process ok.")
        }

    }
  }
```

But in this case I have a new collection of `headers`: `val newHeaders = replaceHeaders(req)`.
But `Akka Http` is more flexible, when I make changes to the `headers` these are immediately available as part of the `request` after `extractRequest`. Every block after `extractRequest` when accessing the `request` will have the `headers` updated.
But in the case of `http4s` (at least in my code) I have to explicitly use `newHeaders` to access the new `headers`.

How can I do the same in `http4s`?

Comment: https://http4s.org/v0.23/docs/middleware.html ?

Comment: Keep in mind the philosophy is way different between Akka HTTP and http4s: http4s sits on the typesafe functional way of the table.